# Running function on submit click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I started off with:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    //Range
    var val = $('#slider').val();
    output = $('#output');
    output.html(val);

    $('#slider').on('change', function() {
      output.html(this.value);
    });

    function showSlider() {
      $('#slider').show();
      $('#textInput').hide();
      output.html('0');
    }

    function showTextInput() {
      $('#slider').hide();
      $('#textInput').show();
      $('#textInput').val('');
      $("#output").html('skin url');
    }

    $('#Main').change(function() {
      switch (this.value) {
        case 'optiona':
          $('#slider').prop({
            'min': 0,
            'max': 20
          });
          showSlider();
          break;
        case 'optionb':
          $('#slider').prop({
            'min': -10,
            'max': 90
          });
          showSlider();
          break;
        case 'optionc':
          showTextInput();
          break;
        case 'optiond':
          showTextInput();
          break;        
        default:
    }
    $('#slider').val(0);
  });

}    

</script>

  <body>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Options</legend>
        <p>
          <label>
            Select option:
          </label>
          <select id="Main" onchange="changeRange('10', '80')">
           <option value="default">select an option</option>
            <option value="optiona">a</option>
            <option value="optionb">b</option>           
            <option value="optionc">c</option>  
            <option value="optiond">d</option>        
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>        
          <span id="output"></span></br>    
          <input type="range" min="0" max="9000" id="slider" value="0" name="range" style="display: inline-block;width: 150px">
          <textarea id="textInput" style="display: none; width: 259px; margin: 0px; height: 15px;"></textarea>          
          <span id="output"></span></br>    
          <input type="submit" onclick="submited()" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 82%;" class="button" id="submitDemo"/>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
```

So far it works fine, I want textboxes for option C and D and rest should have a slider displaying the value, which is does do.

When the submit button is clicked, I want an alert using the value of the options, so I added in this function:

```
  function submited() { 
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("slider").value;
    var finaloutput = $("#output").html()
    if (selectedValue != 'optionc') {
        alert(selectedValue + ' has the value ' + finaloutput);
        }
    if (selectedValue == 'optionc') {
        var textcontent = $('#textInput').val();
        alert('your value is '+ textcontent);
    }
    if (selectedValue == 'optiond') {
        var textcontent = $('#textInput').val();
        alert('your second value of the last option is '+ textcontent);

  };
```

But, I noticed when I clicked the submit button it changed the URL adding the slider range value, instead of alerting with the values of the sliders.

Can someone please help me solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: `changeRange` is not defined

Comment: Hey this looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372273/submit-button-not-executing-function  (Just add `e.preventDefault()` to the function).