# Submit button not executing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code. I want the function submited to run on the submit button click. submited function is meant to alert the value in option and the number on the slider. But, the number of the slider is not being displayed, and the alerts aren't showing:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    //Range
    var val = $('#slider').val();
    output = $('#output');
    output.html(val);

    $('#slider').on('change', function() {
      output.html(this.value);
    });

    function showSlider() {
      $('#slider').show();
      $('#textInput').hide();
      output.html('0');
    }

    function showTextInput() {
      $('#slider').hide();
      $('#textInput').show();
      $('#textInput').val('');
      $("#output").html('skin url');
    }

    $('#Main').change(function() {
      switch (this.value) {
        case 'optiona':
          $('#slider').prop({
            'min': 0,
            'max': 20
          });
          showSlider();
          break;
        case 'optionb':
          $('#slider').prop({
            'min': -10,
            'max': 90
          });
          showSlider();
          break;
        case 'optionc':
          showTextInput();
          break;
        case 'optiond':
          showTextInput();
          break;        
        default:
    }
    $('#slider').val(0);
  });
  function submited() { 
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("slider").value;
 var finaloutput = $("#output").html()
    if (selectedValue != 'optionc') {
  alert(selectedValue + ' has the value ' + finaloutput);
        }
    if (selectedValue == 'optionc') {
     var textcontent = $('#textInput').val();
     alert('your value is '+ textcontent);
    }
    if (selectedValue == 'optiond') {
        var textcontent = $('#textInput').val();
     alert('your second value of the last option is '+ textcontent);
    
  };
}    

</script>

  <body>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Options</legend>
        <p>
          <label>
            Select option:
          </label>
          <select id="Main">
           <option value="default">select an option</option>
            <option value="optiona">a</option>
            <option value="optionb">b</option>           
            <option value="optionc">c</option>  
            <option value="optiond">d</option>        
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>        
          <span id="output"></span></br>    
          <input type="range" min="0" max="9000" id="slider" value="0" name="range" style="display: inline-block;width: 150px">
          <textarea id="textInput" style="display: none; width: 259px; margin: 0px; height: 15px;"></textarea>          
          <span id="output"></span></br>    
          <input type="submit" onclick="submited()" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 82%;" class="button" id="submitDemo"/>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Please see the code snippet and you can understand my issue.

Any help is appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: what is error in console ?

Comment: Submit is for forms to send it's data to a server.

Comment: Because the submitted function is not global....

Comment: Stop the form from being submitted with `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @zer00ne i put this outside the <form> tag `<button onclick="submited()" style="margin-left: 82%;" class="button" id="submitDemo">Submit</button>` still didnt work

Comment: @JosanIracheta please can you show an example

Comment: Place the button anywhere then change `type` from `"submit"` to `"button"` see updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several errors with your code:

- You are missing a closing `}` when defining your `onload` function
- Your functions are in the wrong scope -- take them out of the `onload` function and place them in the global scope
- Change your HTML button to `type="button"` because you are not submitting a form in this case.
- You should be grabbing `#Main` for the `selectedValue`, not `#slider`.
- From your `<select>`'s `onchange`, you are calling a function `changeRange` that does not exist. Remove the `onchange` attribute.

After making those changes, you get working code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    //Range
    var val = $('#slider').val();
    output = $('#output');
    output.html(val);

    $('#slider').on('change', function() {
      output.html(this.value);
    });

    $('#Main').change(function() {
      switch (this.value) {
        case 'optiona':
          $('#slider').prop({ 
            'min': 0,
            'max': 20
          });
          showSlider();
          break;
        case 'optionb':
          $('#slider').prop({
            'min': -10,
            'max': 90
          });
          showSlider();
          break;
        case 'optionc':
          showTextInput();
          break;
        case 'optiond':
          showTextInput();
          break;        
        default:
    }
    $('#slider').val(0);
  });   

};

 function showSlider() {
      $('#slider').show();
      $('#textInput').hide();
      output.html('0');
    }

    function showTextInput() {
      $('#slider').hide();
      $('#textInput').show();
      $('#textInput').val('');
      $("#output").html('skin url');
    }

  function submited() { 
  
    console.log("submitted");
    
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("Main").value;
   var finaloutput = $("#output").html()
    if (selectedValue != 'optionc') {
  alert(selectedValue + ' has the value ' + finaloutput);
        }
    if (selectedValue == 'optionc') {
     var textcontent = $('#textInput').val();
     alert('your value is '+ textcontent);
    }
    if (selectedValue == 'optiond') {
        var textcontent = $('#textInput').val();
     alert('your second value of the last option is '+ textcontent);
    
   };
  }  

</script>

  <body>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Options</legend>
        <p>
          <label>
            Select option:
          </label>
          <select id="Main">
           <option value="default">select an option</option>
            <option value="optiona">a</option>
            <option value="optionb">b</option>           
            <option value="optionc">c</option>  
            <option value="optiond">d</option>        
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>        
          <span id="output"></span><br>    
          <input type="range" min="0" max="9000" id="slider" value="0" name="range" style="display: inline-block;width: 150px">
          <textarea id="textInput" style="display: none; width: 259px; margin: 0px; height: 15px;"></textarea>          
          <span id="output"></span><br>    
          <input type="button" onclick="submited();" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 82%;" class="button" id="submitDemo"/>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your line `var selectedValue = document.getElementById("slider").value;`
with this one `var selectedValue = document.getElementById("Main").value;`

it should give you the expected output

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    //Range
    var val = $('#slider').val();
    output = $('#output');
    output.html(val);

    $('#slider').on('change', function() {
      output.html(this.value);
    });

    function showSlider() {
      $('#slider').show();
      $('#textInput').hide();
      output.html('0');
    }

    function showTextInput() {
      $('#slider').hide();
      $('#textInput').show();
      $('#textInput').val('');
      $("#output").html('skin url');
    }

    $('#Main').change(function() {
      switch (this.value) {
        case 'optiona':
          $('#slider').prop({
            'min': 0,
            'max': 20
          });
          showSlider();
          break;
        case 'optionb':
          $('#slider').prop({
            'min': -10,
            'max': 90
          });
          showSlider();
          break;
        case 'optionc':
          showTextInput();
          break;
        case 'optiond':
          showTextInput();
          break;        
        default:
    }
    $('#slider').val(0);
  });
  function submited() { 
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("Main").value;
 var finaloutput = $("#output").html()
    if (selectedValue != 'optionc') {
  alert(selectedValue + ' has the value ' + finaloutput);
        }
    if (selectedValue == 'optionc') {
     var textcontent = $('#textInput').val();
     alert('your value is '+ textcontent);
    }
    if (selectedValue == 'optiond') {
        var textcontent = $('#textInput').val();
     alert('your second value of the last option is '+ textcontent);
    
  };
}    

</script>

  <body>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Options</legend>
        <p>
          <label>
            Select option:
          </label>
          <select id="Main">
           <option value="default">select an option</option>
            <option value="optiona">a</option>
            <option value="optionb">b</option>           
            <option value="optionc">c</option>  
            <option value="optiond">d</option>        
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>        
          <span id="output"></span></br>    
          <input type="range" min="0" max="9000" id="slider" value="0" name="range" style="display: inline-block;width: 150px">
          <textarea id="textInput" style="display: none; width: 259px; margin: 0px; height: 15px;"></textarea>          
          <span id="output"></span></br>    
          <input type="submit" onclick="submited()" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 82%;" class="button" id="submitDemo"/>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
```